# Cassandra column name abstraction, 22 or 220 column names. What are the consequences?

Tags: cassandra

I am designing a Cassandra database for a spa clinic that needs to collect a subset of data for each client visit from up to 300 types of unique column values.  I am trying to weigh the potential tradeoffs between 2 Cassandra data models.  The first model has more than 200 unique column names, one for each client data point.

The second model uses 22 polymorphic columns which take different values dependent on the row_format value. Each row_format value will have a unique set of column labels used in dashboards and reports to distinguish the data points.

For both models, each row defined by the row_format and timestamp cluster columns, will typically have only 3 to 10 cells. The database will be creating a permanent client encounter record and so they will be no deletes or updates.

I have set up several UX dashboards with column name labels which properly distinguish the different client data values with the polymorphic abstracted column_name model.  This is working well at a small scale.

```
//Abbreviated table with 200 to 300 column names w/ row_format prefixes

CREATE TABLE encounter_records
(
client_id  text,
row_format  tinyint,
ts  timestamp,
address_city  text,
address_state  text,
address_street  text,
address_zip text,
name_first  text,
name_last  text,
name_middle  text,
name_mothers_maiden  text,
numbers_mobile_phone  text,
numbers_home_phone  text,
numbers_socal security  text,
pain1_bodysite  text. 
pain1_description  text,
pain1_severity  tinyint,
pain1_initial_report_date  date,
pain1_initial_severity  text,
restriction_description  text,
restriction_severity  tinyint,
restriction_initial_report_date  date,
restriction_initial_severity  text,
. . . . 
ETC,
"200 more column names"
)
 PRIMARY KEY ((client_id), row_format, ts)
 WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts DESC);


//Table with 22 polymorphic abstracted column names

CREATE TABLE records_historical 
(
Client_id  text,
row_format  tinyint,
ts  timestamp,
date1 date
lists1  list,
lists2  list,
maps1 map,
maps2 map,
note1  text,
note2  text,
note3  text,
note4  text,
note5  text,
note6  text,
number1  tinyint, 
number2  varint, 
number3  varint, 
number4  varint, 
number5  varint, 
number6  varint,
set1  set
set2  set
)
PRIMARY KEY ((client_id), row_format, ts)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts DESC);
```

I am concerned about what the consequences may be when the database is scaled larger or when I introduce spark for query searches or other tools.  What are the cons of using column name abstraction versus using hundreds of column names?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, especially if these fields change over time would be better to add a "key" clustering key and blob value like:

```
CREATE TABLE encounter_records (
  client_id  text,
  row_format  tinyint,
  ts  timestamp,
  key text,
  value blob,
  PRIMARY KEY ((client_id), row_format, ts, key)
```

This also allows the client to page through the results mid row (set fetch size) which can be more efficient GC wise. If you are pulling full row and theres 200 cells in it the driver has to pull all the row at once which can be rather large.

It depends a lot on how you intend to read or write it. If your always updating everything, and always reading everything storing entire set in a blob (ie protocol buffer) or json string. If your going to update individual fields having a `key` there will allow single field reads/writes.